# juju openstack bundle

Tags: juju, openstack

Machine Configuration:

- Dell R900
- 32GB RAM,
- 4 Quad Core @ 2.4 (16 cores)
- 1 Virtual Drive configured 500 GB

My question for the day is I am deploying the openstack bundle with juju using 12.04 LTS. When deploying a bundle are the relationships expected to be established when its done, and the right services exposed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the bundles contain all of the relationships, and configuration values. You can see these by opening the bundle deployer YAML file in your text editor.

Currently, some bundles require you to modify one or more of their service settings prior to deploying ex) bundles which include ceph https://jujucharms.com/precise/ceph-18/#bws-readme.

Comment: What would you suspect to be the longest amount of time to deploy and create the relationships? Would that be 8 hours?

Comment: It's impossible to say, the duration of deployment is highly dependant on the machine/environment and the services being deployed. The relationships will be created once both services have reported that they are running.